# How to load array with values using helm (Go template)

Tags: yaml, environment-variables, kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I have the following content in a yml file:

```
values:
    my_values:
        - value_1
        - value_2
        - value_3
```

I also have a _env file where I try to load those values in a list:

```
- name: VALUES_IN_LIST
  value:|
      {{- range .Values.values.my_values }}
          {{ . | quote }}
      {{- end }}
```

I'm using SpringBoot and I also have a configuration class, similar to:

```
@Configuration
@Setter
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "values")
public class MyValues {

    private List<String> my_values;

    public List<String> getMyValues() {
        return my_values;
    }
}
```

For testing purposes, I introduced an endpoint, where I call getMyValues() and print both, the content of the list and its size.

The content is correctly loaded inside the list: [value_1 value_2 value_3],
but the size is 1.
Somehow those values are interpreted as a single string.

I need help in customizing a bit that _env file, to treat the values as separate strings inside the list.
Thank you!

I have tried several other formats for the _env file.. also read about the append method and "list"   method, but nothing seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth reviewing Spring Boot's rules on property binding, especially [Binding From Environment Variables](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.relaxed-binding.environment-variables).

Given that `@ConfigurationProperties` class, individual list items will have Spring property names `values.myValues[0]`, `values.myValues[1]`, and so on.  Using the rules for environment-variable binding, these will map to environment variables `VALUES_MYVALUES_0`, `VALUES_MYVALUES_1`, *etc.*

In a Helm context, then, you need to iterate through the list with `range` but also know the current list index.  If you use the range-with-assign format, you can get both the current index and the current list item in local variables (see the Go [`text/template`](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template) documentation in the [Variables](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template#hdr-Variables) section).

```yaml
env:
{{- range $i, $v := .Values.values.my_values }}
  - name: VALUES_MYVALUES_{{ $i }}
    value: {{ quote $v }}
{{- end }}
```

(Depending on what you're trying to set, it may be more straightforward to construct either a YAML file or a Java properties file in a ConfigMap, mount that into a container, and point the application at it as described in [External Application Properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.files).)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but: 
There is another yml file, with the format: 

values:
    my_values: {VALUES_IN_LIST}

So I can't manipulate, the values one by one, by index ... I need all of them loaded in VALUES_IN_LIST, as a list with size 3.. there must be something we are missing at this point: 

value:|
      {{- range .Values.values.my_values }}
          {{ . | quote }}
      {{- end }} 

some manipulation should be done, so the list will treat the values as being independent, and not a single string.

Comment: An environment variable can only have a single-string value.